# convert website to mobile friendly version

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, uiwebview

I'm displaying news feeds from google and I want to convert this pages to a mobile friendly version. I'm using UIWebView to display the news content and I used Read It Later to convert the page using their API

```
    http://text.readitlaterlist.com/v2/text?apikey=yourapikey&url=http://readitlaterlist.com/api/docs
```

This does the job but it's not quite good enough, Do you guys know any alternative for this?

Answer (score 0):

Google Web Toolkit have a "mobilizer" feature that you can find at http://www.google.com/gwt/n. Knowing Google there might be even some API for this.